# Java KeyBindings: How does it work?

Tags: java, key-bindings

I keep seeing that I should use Key Bindings instead of KeyListeners. So I found this page: [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). I read through it and tried to implement it.

```
    Action numPressed = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("hi");
        }
    };
    this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("1"), "released");
    this.getActionMap().put("released", numPressed);
```

I decided to just see what would happen. The class this is in extends a JPanel. Earlier, I used `this.setFocusable(true)`. However, I don't see anything happen when I type '1'. What am I doing wrong? How are Key Bindings supposed to be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example will only work IF the panel has focus, try using `getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)` instead.

You may also find that your `KeyStroke` statement won't work either, I'd suggest trying to use `KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0, true)` instead, which will provide you with a `KeyStroke` object that will respond to key releases.

**Updated with example**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestKeyBindings04 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestKeyBindings04();
    }

    public TestKeyBindings04() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0, false), "pressed");
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0, true), "released");

            am.put("pressed", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Pressed");
                }
            });

            am.put("released", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("released");
                }
            });

            setFocusable(true);
            requestFocusInWindow();        
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, but I already used the method `setFocusable(true)`. Won't that give the panel focus?

Comment: @gangqinlaohu When I plugged that code into Eclipse, it told me that I needed to override `actionPerformed`.  Maybe that will work.

Comment: @gangqinlaohu `setFocuable` means that the component CAN receive focus, not that it has focus.  You example registers a key only when the component has focus.  Use `requestFocusInWindow` to try and gain focus for the component.

Comment: Does the code inside TestKeyBindings04() matter? Does it need to have all the stuff there? Can the run() method and the try catch be ignored, with the other stuff moved into the main method?

Comment: @gangqinlaohu No.  You can move the code from the constructor (as it is) to the `main` method, but it must be executed this way. All UI code must be executed within the context of the EDT. The "main" thread that calls your `main` method is not executed within the EDT, thus, you MUST resync it.  Take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html). The other problem is, I rely on a non-static inner class, which means if you move the code, it will no longer compile

Comment: @gangqinlaohu Sorry, you can ignore the `UIManager.setLookAndFeel` stuff if you wish...

Comment: Odd, I've made plenty of programs with GUIs but I've never used that sort of thing.

Comment: @gangqinlaohu Have a read of the Initial Threads link in the previous comment.  It's not very well document (and even the examples from the official tutorials often don't included), but I can assure you, it's very much required.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27360/discussion-between-gangqinlaohu-and-madprogrammer)