# Key bindings - info. on key release

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I am making a game, when I press the right key my ship starts spinning right which is good.
But I cannot figure out how to get information for when I release the key.

board.java

```
public Board()
{
    setFocusable(true);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setDoubleBuffered(true);

    helper = new Helper();

    player = new Ship();

        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0),
                           "PlayerRight");
        this.getActionMap().put("PlayerRight",
                             new KeyBoardControl(player,"ArrowRight"));

    isRunning = true;
    gameLoop();

}
```

keyBoardControl.java

```
public class KeyBoardControl extends AbstractAction
{
public String key;
public Ship player;

public KeyBoardControl(Ship player ,String key)
{
    this.player = player;
    this.key = key;
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 
{
    player.keyPressed(key);
}

}
```

Ship.java

```
public void keyPressed(String key)
{
    //int key = e.getKeyCode();
   // double angle = helper.getAngle(rotation - 90);

    if (key.contentEquals("ArrowRight"))
    {
        dRotation = 7;
    }

}
public boolean keyReleased(String key)
{
    if (key.contentEquals("ArrowRight"))
    {
        dRotation = 0;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is there a key event for VK_Right release? or is there something other than the Keystroke object to use?
I was using a key listener but I had a problem where it would not detect over 2 key presses correctly so I went for key binding.

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I have had a look. 
Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers

Comment: this.getInputMap()/getActionMap() == nothing in this case, you need to determine JComponent (or container)

Comment: oops copied the wrong bit of code, will change that now

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: "this." refers to "public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener"

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE, just about JFrame, one JPanel and with KeyBindings, otherwise search here, by using key-bindings tag

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on another stack overflow question. [Java KeyBindings: How does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15753551/java-keybindings-how-does-it-work)

I changed my code to

```
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0,false),
                           "PlayerRight");
        this.getActionMap().put("PlayerRight",
                             new KeyBoardControl(player,"ArrowRight"));

        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0,true),
                           "PlayerRightRelease");
        this.getActionMap().put("PlayerRightRelease",
                             new KeyBoardControl(player,"ArrowRightRelease"));
```

Thanks for all the help.